# How to delete text until symbol is found on the left of the match including the symbol and until the symbol is found at the right

Tags: python, string, bash

I would like to clear our first string in the quotes of this example:

```
set dstaddr "somename 10.108.41.90" "somename 10.108.148.53"
```

I would like following result:

```
set dstaddr "somename 10.108.148.53"
```

Could you please suggest how to to achieve it in bash?
I am not interested only to remove first match in quotes but I am interested to remove matched IP address ranges from 10.108.41.0/24 or those that contain 41 in the third octet along with their names and remove them.

Logic should be :
Okey script if you find hosts within subnet 10.108.41.0/24 please remove them from the string along with their names but do not touch other objects.

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

```sh
echo 'set dstaddr "somename 10.108.41.90" "somename 10.108.148.53"' \
| perl -pe 's/\b(\S+)\b.*?\1/$1/'
```

```
set dstaddr "somename 10.108.148.53"
```

- `\b(\S+)\b` finds a *word* and remembers it
- `.*?\1` finds some characters followed by that word
- `s/pattern/$1/` replaces the patten with the captured word

Comment: You did know (from your 'score' I would say so) that SO has a policy of not wanting to be a dial-a-coder website?

Comment: Hello Jackman,
your suggestion also works only for the first match.
If I add additonal "somename <IP address>" it does not work

Comment: You didn't specify that in your question. But change `.*?` to `.*` to make the regex match more greedy.

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
awk '{print $1 " " $2 " " $5 " " $6}' test.txt
```

I simply use the space as a delimiter for the `awk` command. This obviously only works if `somename` does not contain any space character.